# Visual Studio suddenly shows new strange window I haven't seen before

Tags: visual-studio

I'm pretty sure I managed to click on some keybinding without noticing, but I've never seen this "tool" before, making it quite difficult to google it.

Here's an image of my editor:

[image]

I marked the strange window in blue.

Perhaps someone could tell me what this is, and how to remove it again?

Comment: Did you try resetting the window layouts? I believe it is `ALT`+`W`+`R`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I haven't but just did. No change though, it's still there.

Comment: It is not a tool window and these comboboxes are always there.  They just grew a lot bigger.  It is a known problem, seems to strike most often with JavaScript and TypeScript code.  Something to do with them reserving enough space to show functions that have a lot of arguments.  This issue does seem to require a good repro to get resolved, you can send it to connect.microsoft.com